# Editing 'My Logins' doesn't seem to work, can't merge accounts

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts, merge-accounts

I'm having trouble getting my accounts merged.

It's about merging

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/2378523/not-sehe
- *into* https://stackoverflow.com/users/85371/sehe

I followed the instructions

```
https://stackoverflow.com/contact/user-merge
```

But I can't get it to work. Specifically, I can't add my SE account following the steps in https://stackoverflow.com/contact/edit-logins. Instead of adding the account to 'my logins', it just logs me off switching to the other account, and nothing else seems to happen.

Can anyone help me get things unwedged?

---

**Note 1:** As you will probably guess, I'm quite keen on merging in the right direction, in case I could lose badges/rep in the process :)

**Note 2:** I have used the [temporary account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2378523/sehe) named `not-sehe` for a while in order to dissociate my google login from the SO logon . The goal was to spend less time on SO by just not getting automatically logged in. That worked.

Comment: Now all I need to do is to find some unclaimed, deleted high rep user accounts ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your accounts have now been merged, enjoy!

The reason the instructions didn't work is you're a well established user.  Instead of auto-merging "very large" users (lots of posts, rep, etc.), those specific cases are queued for a developer or community team member to take a look before approving.  This means it's not auto and instant, but it also means we're safer since undoing a merge is a mess.  I'm just kidding on the mess part, it's a *royal pain in the ass*.

Comment: Cool. That seems a wise policy. Cheers!